Is it haram to pray to Allah to harm me?
I know self-harm is haram in Islam. But what happens if I pray to Allah to do harm to me?

He might simply give you the harm you asked for ... like he did give what cheap food Israelite asked in place of the heavenly food they were receiving,  or like he did give prison to Joseph PBUH when he asked for, and the prison had included hunger/torture/... . Once Imam Sdaiq PBUH was asked about this demand of Joseph PBUH, and Imam answered Joseph PBUH did asked a wrong request, and he could instead ask for exemption from that intense situation because of those lustful Egyptian women. Joseph PBUH thought this solution to be the best solution possible, but Allah knows best what solution is the best, and it is better to let Allah decides what is better for us. So do not ask for harm, and instead ask for whatever Allah knows to be better for you.

The Prophet ﵌ forbade praying against oneself:

لا تدعوا على أنفسكم ولا تدعوا على أولادكم ولا تدعوا على أموالكم لا توافقوا من الله ساعة يسأل فيها عطاء فيستجيب لكم
Do not pray against yourselves, do not pray against your children, and do not pray against your wealth, lest that coincide with an hour when Allah is asked and He answers your prayers.
— Muslim

